# How to fill a TextBox type date with today's date VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date, datetime, datetime-format

I am trying to fill a TextBox, type date in Visual Basic, with the today's date. (Format dd/MM/yyyy) I tried differents solutions that I got it on the web, but they did not do it.

For example. Today's date is 03/29/2017. I need that when I load the page, the TextBox looks like this:

[image: TextBox date ok]

But the problem is when I load the page, the TextBox appears like this:

[image: TextBox date]

**These are some solutions that I got it in the web.**

```
TextBox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

Dim today As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
TextBox.Text = today

TextBox.Text = Date.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

Dim today As String = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now)
TextBox.Text = today

TextBox.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

TextBox.Text = Text = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString()
```

It matters that I am doing this on Page_Load event handler calling a method. The TextBox is only one in the form called with specific ID.
Also Is important that this TextBox could be edit.

Comment: "they did not work" doesn't tell us anything useful.

Comment: All of those should "work". Can you explain more what "did not work" means, in your case ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Page_Load event"? If it is not Form_Load, maybe a Application.DoEvents() or a Me.Update() may help.

Comment: You need to address the textboxes like:
textbox1.text or textbox2.text etc and not just textbox.text

Comment: "They did not work" I changed the explanation, I add an example.

Answer (score 0):

Old, but was promoted to the front page without a meaningful answer, so here goes:

---

The problem is the control shown here is **not a simple TextBox**. Instead, it looks like a calendar control of some kind.

This control is parsing the input to a DateTime value and showing it on the screen based on it's own internal code or configuration. Probably there's a property you can use to adjust this, but it might also be looking at the default date format of your local system or even just be using a fixed format.

The solution, then, is to explore the formatting options provided by the control and giving it the bare DateTime value, rather than trying to pre-format anything.